# MySQL JOIN select only one row from second table

Tags: mysql

I have got a MySQL query

```
SELECT SensorName FROM Table1 WHERE Name = 'MyName';
```

lets say, I get 5 rows back

```
 Sensor1,
 Sensor2,
 Sensor3,
 Sensor4,
 Sensor5
```

Now in a different table, I have one row of data, this is the query

```
SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 from Table2 Where Name = 'MyName';
```

and this is what I get back.

```
value1      value2       value3     value        value5
23.1669     14.5974     22.4009     19.9076     33.1585
```

"Name" is the common field on both the tables

Now I know these two are mapped (sensor names are mapped with the values), so How can I get Something like in single MySQL query

```
  NAME          VALUE
Sensor1         23.1669 
Sensor2         14.5974
Sensor3         22.4009 
Sensor4         19.9076
Sensor5         33.1585
```

Comment: please take the time to read and comment the answers.  tks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SensorName, Value 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name AND Table1.Name = "MyName"
```

or

```
SELECT SensorName, Value 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name 
WHERE Table1.Name = "MyName"
```

will return all matching occurrences.  you must change your Table2 structure to 2 fields (Name and Value).

Comment: I think this is more complicated than that. It looks almost like they're trying to pivot the results? It's not just joining the tables together.

Comment: maybe.  but from his output, i understood that he needed something like this, even if his original table design is not adequate for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :
Select t1.SensorName,t2.value1,t2.value2,t2.value3,t2.value4,t2.value5 from table 2 as t2 INNER JOIN table1 as t1 On table1.NAME=table2.NAME && Tttable1.NAME='MYNAME' && table2.NAME='MYNAME'